# Get activity from the last minute (PHP)

Tags: php

I got some problems, when im trying to fetch the user with lastactivity time (-1 minute) i dont get any result at all.

This is my code:

```
  if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['msg'])) {
      $chatArray = array();
      $s = $_database->query("INSERT INTO chat(`username`, `text`, `date`) VALUES('".$_database->real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."', '".$_database->real_escape_string($_POST['msg'])."', '".TIME()."')");
      $newID = $_database->insert_id;
      $_database->query("UPDATE chatusers SET lastactivity=TIME() WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'");
      $timestamp = (isset($_COOKIE['chatTimestamp'])) ? $_COOKIE['chatTimestamp'] : TIME();

      $q = $_database->query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM chat WHERE `date` > ".$timestamp." ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 24) AS a ORDER BY DATE ASC");
      if ($q->num_rows == 0) { echo '0'; }
      else {
        while ($rad = $q->fetch_array()) {
          // $chatArray["message"][] = array("msgID" => $rad['msgID'], "message" => $rad['text'], "timestamp" => $rad['date'], "date" => date('H:i', $rad['date']), "username" => $rad['username']);

        }
        $query = $_database->query("SELECT * FROM chatusers WHERE `lastactivity` > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 minute)");
        var_dump($query);
        while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
          $chatArray["users"][] = array("username" => $row['name'], "lastactivity" => $row['lastactivity']);
        }
        print_r($chatArray);
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see i update the lastactivity before im trying to fetch the result, and i still get num_rows 0, if i change the select row to `"SELECT * FROM chatusers WHERE lastactivity < (NOW() - 1 minute)"` i get all users in the database.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `time()`, MySQL's `TIME()`, and MySQL's `NOW()` are not identical. Also, system time and the MySQL server time can be on different time zones.

PHP's `time()` returns a timestamp (an integer).

MySQL's `TIME()` returns the time, as in `12:34:31`.

MySQL's `NOW()` returns a date and time string, as in `2015-11-19 12:34:31`.

Fix:

- if you are using a `datetime` column, use SQL `NOW()` in all three statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `SELECT`).
- if you are using a `timestamp` column, use SQL `TIME()` in all three.

Comment: Changed it now, but i still have the same problem, is there a problem because im using int in the db?

Comment: @Tommy See my edit. How is the column `date` in table `chat` defined, exactly?

Comment: The date in chat is no problem, its the lastactivity in chatusers that is the problem

Comment: @Tommy Sorry, you're right - misread your SQL there. In any case, the problem is that `UPDATE chatusers SET lastactivity=TIME()` tries to set `lastactivity` to a time string, as in `12:34:31`. If you are using an `int` for that column, you'll get weird results (probably something like `123431`, which is not likely work with your other logic). Then, your `SELECT`'s `WHERE` condition looks for `lastactivity > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 minute)`, but that is equivalent to, for example, `lastactivity > '2015-11-19 12:33:31'`. That's not going to play nice with your integer value.

Comment: @Tommy So, as I said, pick a format (`datetime` or `timestamp`) and then be consistent in using the right function for that column type.